# Running my Java code and nothing happens

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

```
public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    final Graphics g = j.getGraphics();
    JButton jb = new JButton("Start");
    j.add(jb);
    jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            HeavenlyBiome.spread(g);

        }
    });

}

 }
 ...
 public class HeavenlyBiome {
static Random r = new Random();
public static void spread(Graphics g){
g.setColor(Color.yellow);
int spread = r.nextInt(2)+1;
if (spread==1){
    g.fillRect(0,600,10,10);
}
```

So I run this and everything compiles right with no errors but the problem is that no window appears! If it helps at all, this is all from a package that is not default, and maybe there's something special you need to do when youre using a new package? I dont know because i'm a new coder so any help is appreciated!

Comment: You almost ***never*** get your graphics by calling `getGraphics()` on a component (and certainly not in this situation). Instead do your drawing in the `paintComponent(...)` method of a derivative of JComponent. Again, the tutorials explain all this nicely. Google for them.

Comment: Okay well how should i do that then?

Comment: i havent done any swing in many years. dont you need to show the frame or something?

Comment: Yes, you need a JFrame, but you never draw directly in it. It's all well explained in the tuts. Please check them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `setVisible(true)` on your `JFrame` instance.

```
JFrame j = new JFrame();
JButton jb = new JButton("Start");
j.add(jb);

j.setVisible(true);
```

And read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: @BaconMan: it may show the JFrame, but you still need to fix your graphics. Again, please check out the tuts.

Comment: Though you missed one very important part :-) `pack()` before `setVisible(true)` still +1, for the remaining :-)

Comment: Glad to help :)  Please accept this answer if you would. While not the smartest guy here, I'm trying to break 200 rep! Oh, and as everyone else says, fix your graphics!